# Crear servicio en segundo plano en Ionic

Tags: android, ionic, ios, cordova, ionic4

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación que comunica mi celular con una PCB que he diseñado via Bluetooth. He utilizado los plugins BLE y background mode ambos en la documentación de Ionic y GitHub y me ha funcionado perfectamente. La información que envío a la PCB es cada 5 segundos

El problema es cuando se cierra la aplicación, ya no funciona nada. Tengo claro que al trabajar en ionic estoy usando JavaScript y HTML, y éste tiene que estar ejecutándose para funcionar.

Mi pregunta y solicitud de ayuda, ¿es posible generar un servicio en segundo plano que al cerrar la aplicación arranque el servicio y siga enviando la información? Quiero que la app arranque servicio en segundo plato **tanto en android como en iOS**. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Estos son los métodos que ocupo para enviar el dato

```
enviarDatos() {
var data = this.battery + '*';
this.ble.write(this.mac, "FFE0", "FFE1", this.stringToBytes(data))
  .then(
    () => console.log('mensaje enviado: ' + data),
    error => console.log('error al enviar el mensaje: ' + error)
  );
}

stringToBytes(string) {
  var array = new Uint8Array(string.length);
  for (var i = 0, l = string.length; i < l; i++) {
    array[i] = string.charCodeAt(i);
  }
  return array.buffer as ArrayBuffer;
}
```

Comment: ¿como envías la información? agrega lo que has realizado por favor,saludos,

Comment: He agregado lo que me has pedido

Comment: tienes la solución? no veo nada. A lo mejor te falto subir.

Comment: Tengo exactamente el mismo problema que tu, ¿pudiste solucionarlo? si es así ¿me podrías compartirla por favor? gracias.

Comment: No, amigo aun no he podido solucionarlo, a penas lo tenga comparto la solución

Comment: alguien ha encontrado la solución a este problema?

Comment: Hola, cuando la aplicación se cierra, es por un error, o por una señal que tú mandas?, la cosa es que si puedes controlar eso "La causa de cerrado de tu aplicación", podrás controlar y lanzar un crontab, script o algo similar que inicie el servicio que deseas, pero para eso es necesario saber en que momentos termina la ejecución. Si esta es la respuesta que buscas, coméntamelo y te ayudo a crear el "Re-launch".